# How to attach trigger on ControlTemplate items?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

We are trying to bind Trigger on Stackpanel loaded while using RadMessageBox control. Example :

```
 <!-- CustomMessageBox Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MessageBoxTemplate" TargetType="messageBox:RadMessageBoxControl">
            <Border Padding="12" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Title" Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}"/>

                    <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}"
                                    x:Name="PART_Message"/>

                    <CheckBox x:Name="PART_CheckBox" Grid.Row="2"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

                    <ContentControl x:Name="PART_ButtonsContainer" Grid.Row="3"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0" Width="440">
                        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_ButtonsPanel"
                                        Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding PART_ButtonsPanel}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentControl>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

The ControlTemplate is inside Page.Resources.
We are unable to Trigger stackpanel loaded event. Code behind file :

```
private bool _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute = true;

    bool CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute");

            if (_CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand != null)
                _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<string> _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand;

    public ICommand CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand == null)
            {
                _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoaded, (data) => CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommandCanExecute);
            }

            return _CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand;
        }
    }

    private void CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoaded(object obj)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
```

Comment: just make sure that your StackPanel is getting same class as DataContext or use ancestor binding and use datacontext of page to bind command  and to be sure. your binding and scenario  else looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your CommandBinding. your binding is:

```
 Command="{Binding DataContext.CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand}"
```

that means that in the DataContext class of your control there is any object name DataContext which has CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand as a property in it. But that is not the case. Such type of syntax is used in RelativeSource Binding.

But here change your binding as:

```
Command="{Binding CustomMessageBoxStackPanelLoadedCommand}"
```

So binding engine will now find this command directly inside your DataContext. (I hope there is not any problem with giving datacontext to your views.)

also not sure why you have written

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PART_ButtonsPanel}"
```

like this. what are you trying to do there?